# How to display scrollbar in IE8 when in full screen mode?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Whenever I press f11 to turn my browser into full screen mode, the vertical scroll bar disappears on the right hand side so I cant scroll down the page.  Is there anyway I can show the scroll bar in full screen mode? my body is overflow:visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
overflow: auto; overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: I applied these styles to my body, and no luck :(

Comment: @anthonypliu try forcing then with `overflow: scroll !important; overflow-y: scroll !important;`

Comment: This in the way i used to show scrollers in F11 fullscreen mode. If scrollbars still doesnt show up, then something other problem.. check styles of body or etc..